# is there a way to format the following equations?

Tags: equations

I have the following structure to a set of equations:

```
\begin{align}
\MoveEqLeft eq1 = \\
& eq2term1 eq2term2 \\
& eq3term1 eq3term2
\end{align}
```

Right now eq2term1 and eq2term2 are way too long to appear together in the same line. I want to break it into:

```
\begin{align}
\MoveEqLeft eq1 = & \\
& eq2term1 \\
& eq2term2 \\
& eq3term1 eq3term2
\end{align}
```

However, there is one thing I don't like about this, which is eq2term1 and eq2term2 are aligned to the left the same way. I want to push eq2term2 much further in, so that it is apparent it is a continuation of eq2term1. Is there a way to do that?

I think I could do that by adding spaces before eq2term2, but that doesn't sound the "right" way to do it...

Comment: After your "&" you could insert manual space, say \qquad or similar.

Comment: @Daryl why don't you turn your comment into an answer (adding some example code illustrating your suggestion)?

Comment: Maybe the `multiline` or `split` environment form the [AMSmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package might be useful for you?

Comment: okay, I used the qquad trick Daryl mentioned. It seems to be working well.

Comment: otherwise you could use `\phantom{put something here}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `&`, you could insert manual space, say with `\qquad` or similar.

Example:

```
\begin{align*}
  Something &= short_line\\
  &= long_line_part_1\\
  &= \qquad long_line_part_2 % manually insert space
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Tip: You can highlight code by selecting it and hitting Ctrl + K, or the `{}` button on the toolbar above the text field. This adds backticks (`\``) for inline code and four-space indentation for blocks.

Comment: I'm on a mobile device atm. It is very slow going doing anything. Thanks for the tidy up.

Comment: Ah, I see. No problem.